# Angular 2: Getting Popup Height from DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a "popup" that displays data retrieved from a database on `mousemove` and appears at the mouse location. It looks like this:

```
<div (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)></div>

onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.xCoord = event.x
    this.yCoord = event.y
}

<div [style.left.px]="xCoord" [style.top.px]="yCoord" class="popup">
    ...
</div>
```

Because the dimensions of the popup are dynamic, depending on its content, I need to retrieve the dimensions in order for the popup to be placed properly (above the target and centered horizontally). Is it possible in Angular 2 to get style properties from an element without, for example, a mouse event? Ideally, the dimensions are assigned to a variable when the popup appears.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use basic Javascript to access the DOM element's width and height properties, like so:

**Javascript:**

```
getPopupDimentions() {
   let myElement = getElementById("myPopup");
   return {
      width: myElement.style.width,
      height: myElement.style.height
   }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div [style.left.px]="xCoord" [style.top.px]="yCoord" class="popup" id="myPopup">
    ...
</div>
```

Of course, the Javascript I posted above will need to be called once the popup has been initiated.

---

If you wanted a more *Angular* like approach, I would recommend using a View Child, like so:

**Javascript:**

Make sure you import ViewChild `import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'`

```
@ViewChild('mypopup') mypopup; 

getPopupDimentions() {
   return {
      width: this.mypopup.nativeElement.style.width,
      height: this.mypopup.nativeElement.style.height
   }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div [style.left.px]="xCoord" [style.top.px]="yCoord" class="popup" #mypopup>
    ...
</div>
```

If you want to find out more about Angular view children, I recommend checking out [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template).